# Using Google ID tokens to authenticate a Reactjs Frontend and FastAPI Backend

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, jwt, single-sign-on, fastapi

I'm trying to create a reactjs SPA and make it communicate with a FastAPI backend. My goal is to do stateless authentication which will leverage Google's Oauth SSO but not require a database on the backend. Is this possible?

I've tried a bunch of things but the thing that im stuck on is that everytime someone logs in using Google's SSO from the reactjs app, they receive an ID Token that expires every hour, which means that after one hour, the backend will not be able to authenticate the requests coming from the user.

The Google API only returns an ID token with nothing else, which means I cant refresh the token if it's expired automatically, as I want the users to be logged in without the need to login again every hour.

This is going to be an internal app for my company. So just being able to authenticatle using their coporate google account will be enough, but im not sure how to handle the fact that the ID token expires every hour.

What I've done is the following:

1. React Frontend App initiaties login using [google auth's npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google)
2. User logins in using their coroporate email
3. On success, they receive the ID token and store it in local storage
4. Attach the token on each ongoing request to the backend
5. backend verifies the token and responds accordingly as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)

This is all good and I can just configure the react app to show that the user is logged out when the token expiry date has passed. What is the solution for refreshing this token seamlessly without prompting the user to login again?

I feel like im missing a step here, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. If this is even possible.